# Azure Data Factory data flow writing to sink also creates an empty blob file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sink

I'm new with Azure Data Factory and their data flows. I've created a data flow that compares existing and new data based on an md5hash and writes the inserts/updates to a parquet file in ADLS. However, when writing to the sink with folder path: containername/target with filename option Pattern and the pattern being concat($TargetFileName, toString(currentUTC())), it created a folder 'target' (as I would expect) but also an empty blob named 'target', which I don't understand and can't seem to figure out why it also creates a file.
Any suggestions on how to stop it from creating the target file?

[sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4YDz.png)

[sink settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mxr3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Azure Blob Store as the target and creating a new folder, ADF must place an empty file in that new folder in order to create that folder. This is an Azure Blob Store requirement.